# Client computer(Windows 8.1 Pro) unable to connect to a domain(Windows Server 2012)

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, client-server

I am unable to connect a client pc to a domain controller which is a Windows Server 2012 Datacenter. I have tried connecting it :

1. Through the system menu in Control Panel
2. Putting all the credentials correctly
3. Manually changing it to 'domain' rather than a 'workgroup'
   The error message generated at the end is "Your Computer Could not be joined..."
   "An attempt to **resolve the DNS name of the domain controller in the domain being joined has failed**. Please **verify this client is configured to reach a DNS server** that can resolve DNS names in the target domain."
   N.B : >> ADS, DNS, DHCP Services are installed and on.
            >> The network is LAN connected
            >> I am inexperienced :|

Comment: This looks like a classic DNS problem, but that doesn't mean it is. Can you `ping` the name of your domain controller? Please provide output for command and its result. (Obfuscate with care, as necessary.)

Comment: This was the output
`C:\Users\acer>ping SERVER-BIFBTBI

Pinging SERVER-BIFBTBI [192.168.0.204] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.204: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.204: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.204: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.204: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.204:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the following resolutions in this order (try again after each):

1. Use FQDN: `example.com` instead of just `example`.
2. Check that your DNS server is resolving the server IP correctly.

   - If you are using external DNS servers, they probably won't resolve
     internal addresses. If your domain controller has DNS role, set your
     DHCP to make it the primary DNS server for your network.
   - You can also set the DNS server manually to be the DC during operation.
   - In clients command line, check `nslookup dc.example.com`and see whether the result is the correct IP of your domain controller. (It'll
     also show which name server was used.)
3. Ensure you can connect to the server with this IP address. (`ping`, HTTP, anything...)
4. Temporarily disable Windows Firewall on the client.

   - Also, could any 3rd party firewalls or other security solutions prevent this?
5. Disable IPv6.

Comment: My organisation is not using any external DNS and it is already in the primary role, i came to know this when I was trying to create a new primary one through the DNS Manager. Still facing the same problem.**Should I replace the primary DNS server address in my server to its Ethernet's ip address?**

Comment: The new 3. should help with the question in your comment.

Comment: This was the output of the dc.example.com<br>.

`C:\Users\acer>nslookup SERVER-BIFBTBI.BIFC.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  218.248.241.161

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out`
Whereas I can connect to the server using a remote Desktop Connection or a cmd ping

Answer (score 1):

After all the hectic and researching over the internet, I found out the solution.

- Resetting the router
- **flushdns** the WS2012
- Re-installing the service

Might help others, and thanks @Esa Jokinen, @roaima